# the datetime from the datepicker is always minus 1 hour in odoo 10, python

Tags: python

I have got to add 1 hour to my code but I shouldn't be like this

```
d1= datetime.strptime(record.datetime, DATETIME_FORMAT)+timedelta(hours=1)
```

Comment: What datepicker?

Comment: I meant when I choose the date from the view (it is like calendar)

Comment: You're going to have to provide more code. No one can help you as it is. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: the code i provided is what i i guessed as solution, the problem is :when i choose the datetime from my view what I get when I printed it out or when I want to implement it in my code is the datetime -1 hour  thats why I had to add 1 hour before using it

Answer (score -1):

You should check if the datetime returned from the "view" is in UTC time,
in python you can access to current UTC time using this command:

```
datetime.datetime.utcnow()
```

You should check which timezone you are living in, and see the UTC offset.
This [site](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/) allow you to check your timezone.

Anyway this is the standard way to "play" with the datetime hours/minutes:

```
>>> d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime("09/08/17 16:30", "%m/%d/%y %H:%M")
>>> d1_plus_one_hour = d1 + datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
>>> d1_plus_one_hour
datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 8, 17, 30)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, yes that is perfectly working but if the problem is depending on timezone for example then it may working for me but not somewhere

Comment: I don't think someone is understanding your question ... Can you give examples, or explain it better ?

Comment: when i pick the datetime from my view and when I printed it out or when I implemented it in my codeI get the (datetime -1 hour) thats why I had to add 1 hour before using it, I shouldn't add this 1hour  in my code , it supposed  to work fine

Comment: Where are you living ? maybe it is the UTC time and it's fine,

Comment: Morroco, I ried Africa/Casablanca  in configuration of administrator's timezone but it didn't work